# How to reliably programmatically check whether net5 AspnetCore Hosting Bundle is installed?

Tags: .net

Tried with powershell commands :

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

But, if net5 is installed, both output same lines whenever the Windows Hosting Bundle is installed or not.

Tried to find AspnetCoreModuleV2 in registry, found it... but found it also after uninstalling hosting bundle and restarted the PC.

Searched a lot on Microsoft websites.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found.

first check whether "AspNetCoreModuleV2" is listed with ServerManager :

```
                using ServerManager serverManager = new ();

                var config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
                var globalModulesSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/globalModules");
                var globalModulesCollection = globalModulesSection.GetCollection();

                return globalModulesCollection.Any(m => m.GetAttributeValue("name")?.Equals("AspNetCoreModuleV2") == true);
```

Then, check dotnet desired version with the command

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```